# Multithreaded Linux program not giving expected output

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, printf

This is my code, I compiled it with:

```
gcc thread.c -lpthread
```

It didn't print any error or warning. But when I run it, the program doesn't print anything.

Platform: Ubuntu 11.10 64 bit gcc 4.6.1
Exit status :0

When I debug it, I found it prints `hello` as I expected.

This is my code:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *loopPrint(void *ptr)
{
    char *p = (char *)ptr;
    while (1)
    {
        printf("%s\n", p);
    }
}

void *pClock(void *ptr)
{
    sleep(3);
    exit(0);
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t showMsg, clock;
    int main_pth, wait_pth;
    char *msg = "Hello";
    main_pth = pthread_create(&showMsg, NULL, loopPrint, (void *)msg);
    wait_pth = pthread_create(&clock, NULL, pClock, NULL);

    pthread_join(main_pth, NULL);
    pthread_join(wait_pth, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
pthread_join(main_pth, NULL);
```

This is wrong, `pthread_join` takes a `pthread_t` as an argument. Replace with:

```
pthread_join(showMsg, NULL);
```

(Same for the other one.)

And do check the return values of these calls, they can and do fail.
And BTW, you're missing `#include <unistd.h>` for the sleep call.

Answer (score 2):

`main_pth` etc is the error return of `pthread_create` and not the thread id. Wait ("join") for `showMsg` and `clock`.